# Limit of probability in Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a Markov chain with transition probabilities $P_{ij}$ and asymtotic distribution $\pi_j$. I'm stuck trying to determine the following limits:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(x_n =k, X_{n+1} = j |X_0 = i ) $$
and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(x_{n-1} =k, X_{n} = j |X_0 = i ). $$

I don't have experience working with stochastic process. I'm trying to use the Markov property and the definitios of asyptotic distribution without sucess.

Someone can help me?

Comment: $P(X_n =k, X_{n+1} = j |X_0 = i ) =P_{ik}^{(n)}P_{kj} \to\pi_kP_{kj} $. The other limit is also $\pi_kP_{kj} $.

Comment: I really wonder why there is a close vote here ? Why is this a communtiy specific question ? and by the way what  is a community specific question (I can't find a definition in help or meta site)

Comment: @TheBridge: What has Marco R tried?  For example, have they seen the limiting distribution for irreducible aperiodic chains?  If not, can they compute these sorts of probabilities for finite $n$ in a special case?  Heck, why do they care about these formulas?  None of these are in the question, and they should be.

Comment: If you click on "a community specific reason", you'll see that the community specific reason is "Missing context or other details."

Comment: @Jacob Manaker : Before voting to close a newcommer's question you should leave a comment explaining to the person what he/she should add, this is also in the guidance of this site. unless mistaken Thank for pointing the detail of community specific criteria for closing

Comment: Moreover there exist already the "Needs details or clarity" criteria for closing, the what have you tried should not be mandatory otherwise 2/3 of the questions on this site should be closed IMO.

Comment: @TheBridge: "Before voting to close a newcommer's question you should leave a comment explaining to the person what he/she should add" --- what do you think my comment to you was?  "the what have you tried should not be mandatory" --- Yes, but they still haven't motivated the question by providing any context to give us a sense of what level to pitch answers at.  That _is_ mandatory, and why a large number of questions on this site _are_ closed.

Comment: Anyway context can be quiet subjective, and I disagree with such harsh policy on a newcommer, you should have asked before closing, what precisely you would need to get the context solved from your point of view, and you did that only after voting to close and my first comment. The newcommer expressed the fact that he is a newbie on stochastic process theory in his post (which might explain why his question lacks context), and instead of helping him you are simply closing the door at his face. Real nice !